# Offline button is not active in Disk Management

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a loptop with 2 hard drives , The original one is sata and I added SSD drive to it after I purchase it. with windows 10 installed on it on SSD drive. I offline the sata disk from disk management many times ago, Today I make it online again from disk management to copy some files on it and I installed vmware, after that offline button is not active in disk management and I cannot make disk offline again...
any idea how to solve this problem ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upvyq.png)

I think its because I rebooted the system and now it created recovery partition on the disk and that is the reason it won't let me make it offline...

Comment: Additionally context is required to explain why that option is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by disable creating pagefile on second HDD.
I did it using System properties > Performance > Settings and under virtual memory menu I set no paging file for second HDD
Then I restarted the system and problem solved !